# Customers custom attribute with dropdown is not working

Tags: customer, magento2.3, custom-attributes

I need to create a custom attribute for customer entity with the `Yes/No`.

I tried to use `boolean` type and also `select` method. But nothing has worked.

Below are my work:

## Try 1: (Type as `select`)

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'is_mobile_verified',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Is Mobile Verified?',
                'input' => 'select',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => 'Ucs\Reson8\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => 0,
                'system'       => 0,
                'position'     => 1002,
            ]
        );


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'is_mobile_verified')
        ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
```

`Ucs\Reson8\Model\Config\Source\Options.php` as below

```
<?php

namespace Ucs\Reson8\Model\Config\Source;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
    * Get all options
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options = [
                ['label' => __('No'), 'value'=>'0'],
                ['label' => __('Yes'), 'value'=>'1'],
            ];

    return $this->_options;

    }

}
```

## Try 2: (Type as `boolean`)

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'is_mobile_verified',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Is Mobile Verified?',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => 0,
                'system'       => 0,
                'position'     => 1002,
            ]
        );
$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'is_mobile_verified')
        ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                ]
        ]);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you try updated answer?

Comment: @ARUNPRABAKARANM Yes, No luck

Comment: Finally, I got an solution. Kindly check my updated code

Comment: Hope You Tried my solution.

Comment: I tested the code and it work fine

Comment: @ARUNPRABAKARANM I tried all your solution, and it doesn't work. No log captured as well. I have other observers also, Maybe of them is causing the issue. I will update you

Comment: Later I updated the new code with a screenshot. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: @ARUNPRABAKARANM Yes I did that

Comment: Ok Butterfly. Let us know once you complete

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with below:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_mobile_verified', [
                'label' => 'Is Mobile Verified ?',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'visible' => false,
                'system' => false,
                'type' => 'static',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
                'option' => ['values' => ['Yes', 'No']],
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) 
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Create a select box attribute
         */
        $attributeCode = 'my_customer_type';

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 
            $attributeCode, 
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'My Customer Type',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\MyCustomerType',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 300,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );

        // show the attribute in the following forms
        $attribute = $customerSetup
                        ->getEavConfig()
                        ->getAttribute(
                            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                            $attributeCode
                        )
                        ->addData(
                            ['used_in_forms' => [
                                'adminhtml_customer',
                                'adminhtml_checkout',
                                'customer_account_create',
                                'customer_account_edit'
                            ]
                        ]);

        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

[image]